# Cache issue with WP_Query and custom field filtering

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-query, cache

I have three separate WP_Queries on a page. Each of them return custom post type items that have a certain checkbox checked and then display one of those randomly. The checkbox has been added using [Custom Metaboxes and Fields for WordPress](http://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress).

```
<?php
$front1_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'work-item',
    'meta_key' => '_cmb_work_front_large',
    'meta_value_num' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => '1'
);
$front1_query = new WP_Query($front1_args);
while ($front1_query->have_posts()) : $front1_query->the_post();    
?>
<div> 
  post content comes here
</div>
<?php 
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

However unpicking the checkbox on a certain post sometimes has no effect. The query still returns all items that at some point have had the checkbox checked regardless if they have it now. Setting `cache_results`, `update_post_meta_cache` and `update_post_term_cache` to false has no effect.

Any ideas what might cause this? Is this a cache issue at all, or is CMB maybe at fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix. Apparently CMB doesn't use integers while saving values to database from custom checkboxes, but rather adds an `on` string when a checkbox is checked.

Also when a previously checked checkbox is unchecked, the corresponding row isn't removed from `wp_postmeta` table, but remains there with an empty value.

So this will return all posts that at some point have had the checkbox active:

```
'meta_key' => '_cmb_work_front_large',
'meta_value_num' => 1
```

And this will show only the active ones:

```
'meta_key' => '_cmb_work_front_large',
'meta_value' => 'on'
```